# Structure dev and prod environments inside MongoDB atlas

Tags: database, mongodb, data-structures, mongodb-atlas

I'm using MongoDB Atlas and I'm trying to figure out how to structure my DBS inside MongoDB Atlas.

I'm want to create 1 DB for dev and 1 DB for prod.

I create an organization and thinking about creating 2 projects: development, production.
Inside the development project, I will create a cluster: app-dev (and inside that cluster my dev DB).

And inside my production project, I will create a cluster: app-prod (and inside that cluster my prod DB).

Should I keep it like that or should I stick to 1 project (because it's the same app) and 1 cluster, and inside that cluster create 1 dev DB and 1 prod DB.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use separate clusters for isolation. There are many cluster-wide operations in MongoDB that can affect your production database if there's a development database running in the same cluster.

If you put both databases on the same cluster, they would also share resources (thus a runaway operation in development would DOS your production site).